# Colored Console Logs Make Log Files Larger?

Tags: node.js, unix

For example... Say I am running a script with Forever https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever for a week while recording a log file of the node applications output.

If I say included colors would it make that filesize bigger? Dealing with crazy sizes logs 5gb+ with the colors on. So curious if I could shave even 10mb without it?

`{
    pass:       [0,255,0],
    fail:       [255,0,0],
    info:       [0,255,255],
    warning:    [255,127,80]
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're storing more characters to colorize log output, so yes, you will increase the log size (more data == more data). For example, check out these source lines from [chalk](https://github.com/chalk/chalk/blob/c2ef5b8c133069e590f7fa62c9613769bc235ae7/test.js#L12) tests:

```
it('should style string', function () {
                                 // Notice all the extra characters
    assert.equal(chalk.underline('foo'), '\u001b[4mfoo\u001b[24m');
    assert.equal(chalk.red('foo'), '\u001b[31mfoo\u001b[39m');
    assert.equal(chalk.bgRed('foo'), '\u001b[41mfoo\u001b[49m');
});
```

If you absolutely need the colors for readability, so be it. But if you do w/o you **can** shave off some space, but there's no guarantee it'll be in the order of 10MB :)

Another thing to note is that depending on where you're reading the logs, the color may or may not come through properly. I've run into this when looking at some raw logs on AWS. The colorized portions were pretty mangled.

Comment: Sort of figured that haha - Just thought it would be a great question to put up on stack overflow for anyone else as well to see the responses I get.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Cool :) do you need any other clarification or is the response accepted as it?

Comment: Sorry for late acceptance asked this while I was at work... hehe thanks!